# Hide DIV after click and show when h press

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have this div:

```
<div id="control">BLABLABLA</div>
```

And i want want when my page load, show it, when we click, i hide it, and if the visitor click on h, the div re-appear?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: what do you mean by `h` here?

Comment: yes, it's a game, and the help it's when guys click on h, i already have key listen on my script.

Comment: ohh. you want to play between two diffrent user, in that case stores its state to database or use websocket

Comment: I'm explaining better lol. The guys load page, I have my div, show control, car we can take...., he clicks anywhere in the div, div it's hidden, he playing.... But don't remember for change car, he press h and the div re-appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  function myFunction(){
     var control = document.getElementById('control');
  var i = document.getElementById('i'); // id of i
  var h = document.getElementById('h'); // id of h
  control.style.display =  "block";
  i.onclick = function(){
  control.style.display = "none";
   };
 h.onclick = function(){
 control.style.display =  "block";
   };
```

}

```
  <body onload="myFunction()">
```

Comment: as i said, it is not tagged as jquery

Comment: yes, thanks i have put:
document.getElementById("controls").onclick = function() {$( "#controls" ).toggle();}  at the beginig, and var controls = document.getElementById('controls');
     controls.style.display =  "block"; for h key press and it's work

Answer (score 0):

May be this should work. I assume that you are meaning `h` as `h1`

```
var div = document.getElementById('control');
div.onclick = function(){
 div.style.display = "none";
};

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].onclick = function(){
div.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: i mean h, in keyword, the key h, like help and manly for help lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Jquery code, then you may do this:--

```
$("#control" ).on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    var div = $("#control" );
    if(key == 72 || key == 104) {
      div.show();
    }
    else if(key == 73 || key == 105) {
      div.hide();
    }
});
```